# How to setup SensioGeneratorBundle in SILEX

Tags: php, symfony, console, silex

For a few days I'm trying to setup SensioGeneratorBundle in Silex but no luck.

composer.json:

```
...
"symfony/console": "^3.2",
"sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.1"
...
```

bin/console.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

use Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand());
$application->run();
```

When i run bin/console.php list, all i get is:

```
Console Tool

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help  Displays help for a command
  list  Lists commands
```

There is no doctrine:generate:entity command.

Help anyone...

Comment: silex? What does bundle have to do with silex?

Comment: it doesn't, it is a part of symphony i would like to integrate in my Silex project.